# Devices connect to hotspot oblivious to proxy settings

Tags: proxy, home-networking, bridge, connection-sharing

Am not sure if I am able to provide a suitable title for my problem. More so trying to explain it, I have drafted an image putting my problem into perspective.[ 
[link to image](https://postimg.org/imag45ej/e/ur4an)]

**Problem.** My institute allows connection to devices through a proxy (12.x.x.x in the example) but sadly my old smartphone(Nokia C series) and Smart TV does not come with option to configure proxy settings in their respective network administration. So I wanted to know if it be possible to :

1. Have my PC connected to the wired LAN. Punch in required proxy settings and create another wireless network to which my phone and TV connect completely oblivious to the proxy. The PC on receiving relevant packets from the devices should route them through the entered proxy.
2. Have similar setup as (1) above but with the PC replaced with a router.

Pardon me if this turns out to be a very basic question but I tried implementing scenario 1 with tools such as ***connectify*** and ***mhotspot***, sadly to no avail.

If not scenario 1 but only scenario 2 is possible to implement(assuming) I would like to know, so that I go ahead and buy a router.

EDIT: Just got my hands on Virtualrouter. Ends up being the same. The proxy settings need to be configured on the devices threre too.

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Sounds like you need a proxy to intercept the connections and pipe them through an upstream proxy.  Our product [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) can do this, and is free for 10 concurrently-connected users.  You will still need to set up the wifi on that PC as an access point, but WinGate can also provide the DHCP to the wireless clients in this case.  DIsclaimer: I work for Qbik who make WinGate.

Comment: just to be sure; This wont require me to enter the new proxy settings (for Wingate) on my TV/phone? Just downloaded the application. Culs you guide me a little with what all policies do I have to tinker around with? Moreover all Wingate services seem to have started except the 'WWW Proxy server' with status as 'Error'.

Comment: Probably something is running on port 80 already like skype or IIS. You can run the WWW proxy on another port and still intercept port 80.

Comment: My questions may just be irrelevant probably. Could you guide me to the provisions of Wingate that need to be worked upon. Yes Proxy server was one, intercept okay, anything else? Will I be require to configure other options. Because even after doing so and linking the upstream proxy, things dont seem to work Pardon me for my networking know how.

Comment: As i read the documentation I see that the Wingate client facilitates the wingate functionalities. Is it mandatory to use WIngate client for my purposes also? I setup the Wingate proxy to intercept port 80 and 443 requests, but to no avail.

Comment: I'd suggest getting onto out support desk as we will be warned off here with too many comments. The client is windows only. I would suggest just intercept port 80 to the proxy and set default gateway of clients to use WinGate's IP.